# How can I specify a map_remote rule in mitmproxy to redirect from a remote HTTPS URL to an HTTP URL?

Tags: mitmproxy

I'd like to set up a map_remote rewrite from an https address to my local machine running a service on http only.

The documentation for the option (https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/) seems to indicate I should do this

`mitmproxy --map-remote "|https://foo.bar.com|http://localhost:8081|"`

But this doesn't seem to rewrite any requests.

What's the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your example is the trailing `|`. Map Remote specifications can either be:

- `|flow-filter|url-regex|replacement` or
- `|url-regex|replacement`

By append a final `|` to your two-part spec, you inadvertedly use the first form, and `https://foo.bar.com` is applied as the filter and not as the url regex. Long story short:

```
mitmproxy --map-remote "|https://foo.bar.com|http://localhost:8081|"  # wrong
mitmproxy --map-remote "|https://foo.bar.com|http://localhost:8081"   # correct
```

You may also find the extended feature documentation at https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#map-remote helpful. :)